# sum of column values from json object and show it in column in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a JSON data and in that JSON data, I am getting the exact information and showing in my UI screen, after that I am totaling the data using nested `foreach` loop, I am able to see the data, and after I want to total the column of the particular id, and show it on UI screen, for that, I am using filter method to separate the id and I am getting the id, but I need to total the value of the id and show it on screen.

How can I do in angular 2

```
 var groups = new Set(this.payments.map(item => item.group))
      this.columnData=[];
      groups.forEach(g => {
        this.columnData.push({
          workerID : g ,
          totalsalary: g,
        values: this.payments.filter(i => i.group === g)

        })
  })
```

Comment: Right now, this question seems like it would be a better fit for [so] because it doesn't seem like there's anything specific to Salesforce here.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: getWorkertotals(WorkerID:any){
   console.log(WorkerID);
   let list: any[] = [];
     var total = 0;
this.payments.forEach((payment, i) => {
       payment.jobs.forEach((job, j)=>{
         job.shifts.forEach((shift, k)=>{
 totalsalary +=((job.wage * shift.hour)+(job.extra_travel_expenses)),
 });

         })
 });
  console.log("final totalsalary is: " + totalsalary);
}